# Automatically add a comment when you vote to close a question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, comments

Currently, automatic comments are always added when you vote to close as a duplicate.

However, it would be nice if, for example, closing as off-topic asking a question or a review on not yet written code, would add an automated comment on the question informing the OP.  I notice that regulars currently do it themselves and pretty much always copy paste the same content, so why not automate it? We're IT'ers after all.

Comment: Regarding the comments, I'm using [Auto Review Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to have a bunch of comments that I've customized for the most common comments I found myself writing.

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with this is that it'll clutter the comments section as the same comment will essentially be repeated up to five times.  As @Simon has mentioned, an app can be used to post customizable canned comments when voting to close.  It really just takes *one* comment to inform the OP.

This is also different from closing as a duplicate because votes for a certain duplicate will automatically upvote the associated comment.  This is only different when users vote to close as *different duplicates*, but that doesn't usually seem to be an issue.

If I'm understanding this correctly, I suppose you're asking if closing as off-topic can be treated the same as closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Why would the same comment be repeated 5 times?  This isn't the case with closing as duplicate's auto-comment.  Any extra vote-to-close as duplicate of the same question show up as upvotes on that comment--not a duplicate comment.

Comment: @nhgrif: I might've misunderstood what skiwi meant, which is why I've mentioned the last sentence.